# Change number of elements in _fields_ at runtime of Structure (ctypes)

Tags: python, ctypes, structure

Using ctypes I have defined the following class:

```
class ListOfVariables(Structure):
   _fields_ = [
                ("name0", c_int),
                ("name1", c_int),
                ("name2", c_int)              
]
```

Is it possible the add one element to the member '*fields*' at runtime? 
So that we can define a new variable in the following manner, for example:

```
cstructA = ListOfVariables(1,2,3,4)
```

or even with another type:

```
cstructB = ListOfVariables(1,2,3,'b')
```

It is a necessity that after modifying the class dynamically the constructor is called with a new number of arguments.

Comment: Have you tried:  `ListOfVariables._fields_.append(("name3",c_int))`? or `ListOfVariables._fields_[0] = ("name0",c_float)`?  Seems like it should work to me, but I don't actually know :)

Comment: Doesn't work. As a result we have: 'TypeError: too many initializers
'.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, because the Structure is supposed to be a C structure --- a fixed size in bytes, with fixed offsets for elements.  You can't change dynamically the layout of a C structure.  What would it mean e.g. for instances already created?

You *can* change dynamically the layout of regular Python objects because, precisely, their implementation under the hood is more complex than a simple C structure.

Depending on what you want, you can create a subclass of ListOfVariables:

```
class ListOfVariables2(ListOfVariables):
    _fields_ = [('extra', c_int)]
```

It means you're defining another C structure that is an extension of the old one.